# Why html2canvas can't convert parsed element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, html2canvas

I am trying to use `ajax`+`html2canvas` to generate shot from other website.

And I use [AjaxCrossOrigin](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/) to get content(worked!).

Now I use `$.parseHTML` to generate element from HTMLstring,but `html2canvas` always return 
`Uncaught TypeError: element.getElementsByTagName is not a function(…)`.

Why this doesn't work??

```js
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
  if($('#url').val()!='')
  $.ajax({
   type:'GET',
   crossOrigin: true, //http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/
   url:$('#url').val(), //website URL
   dataType:'html',
   success:function(e){
    var el=$.parseHTML(e.match(/<body>((.|\n|\r)*)<\/body>/m)[1]); //get content inside <body>
    console.log(el);
    html2canvas(el,{
     onrendered:function(cvs){
      $('body').append(cvs);
     }
    });
   }
  });
 });
```

Comment: Where is your code where you used this `element.getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: `.getElementsByTagName()` is a native JavaScript method of DOM elements. You probably used it with jQuery object.

Comment: @MAZux I use `el.get(0)` to get JavaScript DOM element, but It doesn't work